# How to select relationships spreading from neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

We have a scenario to display relationships spreading pictures(or messages) to user.

For example: **Relationship 1 of Node A has a message "Foo", Relationship 2 of Node 2 also has same message "Foo" ... Relationship n of Node n also has same message "Foo".**

Now we are going to display a relationship graph by query Neo4j.

This is my query:

```
MATCH (a)-[r1]-()-[r2]-()-[r3]-()-[r4]
WHERE a.id = '59072662'
and r2.message_id = r1.target_message_id
and r3.message_id = r2.target_message_id
and r4.message_id = r3.target_message_id
RETURN r1,r2,r3,r4
```

The problem is, this query does not work if there are only 2 levels of linking. If there is only a r1 and r2,  this query returns nothing.

Please tell me how to write a Cypher query returns a set of relationships of my case?

Comment: Please add a more detailed domain model, picture, don't talk about generic nodes and relationships, no one will be able to help you with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Stefan's answer.

If you want to keep track of how pictures spread then you would also include a relationship to the image like:

```
(message)-[:INCLUDES]->(image)
```

If you want how a specific picture got spread in the message network:

```
MATCH (i:Image {url: "X"}), p=(recipient:User)<-[*]-(m:Message)<-[*]-(sender:User)
WHERE (m)-[:INCLUDES]->(i) WITH length(p) as length, sender ORDER BY length
RETURN DISTINCT sender
```

This will return all senders, ordered by path length, so the top one should be the original sender.
If you're just interested in the original sender you could use `LIMIT 1`.

Alternatively, if you find yourself traversing huge networks and hitting performance issue because of the massive paths that have to be traversed, you could also add a relationship between the message and the original uploader.

The answer to the question you psoted at the bottom, about the way to get a set of relationships in a variable length path:

You define a path, like in the example above

```
p=(recipient:User)<-[*]-(m:Message)<-[*]-(sender:User)
```

Then, to access the relationships in that path, you use the `rels` function

```
RETURN rels(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide much details on your use case. From my experience I suggest that you rethink your way of graph data modelling.

A message seems to be a central concept in your domain. Therefore the message should be probably modeled as a node. To connect (a) and (b) via message (m), you might use something like `(a)-[:SENT]->(m {message_id: ....})-[TO:]->(b)`.

Using this (m) could easily have a `REFERS_TO` relationship to another message making the query above way more graphy.

Comment: Hi Stefan, we already had nodes in this model. Is it possible to have such a query?

Comment: r1, r2,.. are relationships modeling messages in your model, aren't they? I suggest to refactor this into nodes modeling messages so you can keep in-graph references between them as opposed to like them implicitly by matching properties.

Comment: Hi Stefan, we already had nodes in this model which means users. Is it possible to have a query relationships within a graph? Thanks!